# VSTS Hosted Agent Builds won't run in parallel

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

Seems to be a bug in Visual Studio Team Services such that while I have 2 hosted agents rented through azure I'm still unable to run more than one build at a time. The other build waits queued until the first build completes

- I have rented the 2 agents through the azure profile
- I can see the 2 agents in the hosted queue
- I have selected the hosted pool for both builds
- When I check what's happening on each hosted build server they both say they are running the appropriate build but one says it's queued.
- There are no other builds or deployments currently running

Any ideas?

Comment: are these two builds from the same build definition?

Comment: I've tried both not using the same build definition and using the same build definition, both produce the same result.

Comment: Ok thanks for the precision, because when using the same build definition I think the default behavior is that builds are queued, not in parallel. I'd have to check though.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, this should work. The only two things I can think of, which would prevent parallel builds are:

1. A build consumes 2 agents, e.g. is set to compile two build configurations in parallel. Take a look at your hosted pool consumption during builds and you should see if both agents are busy and what they are doing.
2. You are also utilizing other hosted pools, e.g. hosted linux, hosted macOS, hosted VS2017 - all those share the limit of running agents with the hosted pool, so with limit of 2, if you have something running on 1 agent in "hosted linux", then you can run only 1 more in any "hosted X" pools.